# JSF / Jboss / Eclipse: xhtml aren't refresh

Tags: eclipse, jsf-2, jboss5.x

I have a strange problem with my dev environment.

I use Eclipse Indigo with Jboss 5 and JSF 2.

When my server run, xhtml pages aren't refresh when I change them in the IDE.

If the xhtml is in the war, the page is refresh but I have some pages in jar and these pages aren't refresh.

I don't understand the difference between xhtml in war and jar.

Thanks for your help.

Edit: I found a reason about this bug. The directory vfs (the new jboss file system) is not update when I update my jar, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, `.jar` files are compiled projects. Unless you have the source code, make changes to it and re-compile to make a new `.jar` file, anythings inside that `.jar` file cannot be refreshed.

Your `.war` is your current web project. You always clean, build and recompile it every time you run your Project. Hence, you always have the latest changes.

Comment: Yes I have the source code because I develop this jar in same time that the war. When I change a java class, it's update. Just the xhtml aren't update.

Comment: Hmmm... if the `.jar` file is also an ongoing project, I think you shouldn't import it as a `.jar` file. For example, in NetBeans IDE, when you try to import a library, you can choose to import the whole `Project` instead of just the `.jar` file of that `Project`. Any changes you make to that `Project` will be reflected on compiling time.

Comment: In eclipse, my jar project is a eclipse project like the war. When I publish my application in jboss, the jar project is compile as a jar.

Comment: try right clicking on the EAR or WAR on the jboss instance in the server view, and you can "explore" it.  it will open an explorer window to the directory where the project is deployed in the jboss folder. probably, the xhtml file in the jar is still the old one?  I have similar problems, and the only way to resolve it is to do a full deploy (or is it called publish?).  i dont know if that is a bug in the jboss eclipse plugin.

Comment: I tried this but the xhtml in jar is up to date. At the beginning, I thought like you but it's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Doe it have anything to do with?:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
    <param-value>2</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Yes this flag is set to 0. Xhtml in war are refresh, only these in jars aren't